# Is the default DVC behavior to store connection data in git?

Tags: dvc

I've recently started to play with [DVC](https://dvc.org), and I was a bit surprised to see the [getting started docs](https://dvc.org/doc/start/data-and-model-versioning#storing-and-sharing) are suggesting to store `.dvc/config` in git.

This seemed like a fine idea at first, but then I noticed that my Azure Blob Storage account (i.e. my Azure username) is also stored in .dvc/config, which means it would end up in git. Making it not ideal for team collaboration scenarios.

What's even less ideal (read: really scary) is that connection strings entered using `dvc remote modify blah connection_string ...` also end up in `.dvc/config`, making them end up in git and, in the case of open source projects, making them end up in **very** interesting places.

Am I doing something obviously wrong? I wouldn't expect the getting started docs to go very deep into security issues, but I wouldn't expect them to store connection strings in source control either.

My base assumption is that I'm misunderstanding/misconfiguring something, I'd be curious to know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DVC has few "levels" of config, that can be controlled with proper flag:

- `--local` - repository level, ignored by git by default - designated for project-scope, sensitive data
- project - same as above, not ignored - designated to specify non-sensitive data (it is the default)
- `--global` / `--system` - for common config for more repositories.

More information can be found in the [docs](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/config#description).

Comment: Yup, looks like the default is to store info in git, but this can be suppressed with the flags you've highlighted.